# How do I convert JaCoCo report HTML to PDF in Maven GitLab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to store the index.html file from the JaCoCo report by converting into PDF format in the CI/CD pipeline. What is the right command to convert from HTML to PDF in GitLab?

Answer (score 1):

Jacoco does not support pdf natively.
It does generate an html report though.
So you could use a cli tool to convert html to pdf.

For example https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ or pandoc.

You would need to install it in your job/use a docker image that contains it already.

Example:

```yaml
Test:
  image: maven:3.8.3-jdk-11-slim
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent test 
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS jacoco:report 
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml

jacoco2pdf:
  image: riftbit/goracle:alpine-19.3
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd  target/site/jacoco
    - wkhtmltopdf index.html jacoco.pdf
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target/site/jacoco/jacoco.pdf
```

Note that the used docker image is just an example. You should not use it in production unless you verify its contents first.